# jQuery PHP Select Search Results using arrow up and arrow down keys

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

I am building an ajax search and would like to be able to key down and up through the results.  The ajax search and results part is working great, however, I am unable to get the search results to highlight when using the arrow keys...

Here is some of my code:

HTML with sample results:

```
 <div class="searchbox-container">
    <form id="homeSearch">
    <div class="searchbox-box">
        <input type="text" id="search_term" placeholder="Address, School, City, Zip or Keyword..">
    </div>
    <div class="searchbox-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-search"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="searchbox-results" class="searchbox-results" style="">
         <div class="ul-head"><i class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Properties</div>
         <ul>
            <li id="result"><a href="listing/1402+Burnett+Lane+Vincennes+IN/201845998"><b>1402</b> Burnett Lane, Vincennes, IN, 47591</a></li>
            <li id="result"><a href="listing/1402+N+Dewey+Street+Auburn+IN/201911897"><b>1402</b> N Dewey Street, Auburn, IN, 46706</a></li>
            <li id="result"><a href="listing/1402+Sugar+Water+Court+Russiaville+IN/201913291"><b>1402</b> Sugar Water Court, Russiaville, IN, 46979</a></li>
            <li id="result"><a href="listing/14023+Aloes+Passage+Fort+Wayne+IN/201916086"><b>1402</b>3 Aloes Passage, Fort Wayne, IN, 46845</a></li>
            <li id="result"><a href="listing/1402+Main+Street+Frankfort+IN/201919194"><b>1402</b> Main Street, Frankfort, IN, 46041</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax Search:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#search_term').keyup(function() {

    var search_term = $('#search_term').val();

    if (search_term == "") {
        $('.searchbox-results').html("");
        $('.searchbox-results').hide();
    } else {

        if (!search_term.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
          return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_search.php",
                data: {
                    search_term: search_term
                },
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#searchbox-results').removeClass('hidden');
                    fill(html);
                    $('.searchbox-results').html(html).show();
                }
            })
        }
    }

});
});
```

Search Selection

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var result = $('li');
var resultSelected;

$('#search_term').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 40) {
        if (resultSelected) {
            resultSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = resultSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                resultSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                resultSelected = result.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    }

    if(e.which === 38) {

    }
});
});
```

The PHP which returns the result (to see unordered list structure)

```
// Properties
    if ($addr_num != 0) {
        echo '<div class="ul-head"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Properties</div>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($addr_result = mysqli_fetch_array($addr_res)) {

            // Variables for URL
            $url_addr = str_replace(" ", "+", ucwords(strtolower($addr_result['L_Address'])))."+";
            $url_addr .= str_replace(" ", "+", ucwords(strtolower($addr_result['L_City'])))."+";
            $url_addr .= $addr_result['L_State'];

            // Bold Matched Text
            $word = $search_term;
            $pattern = "/$word/i";
            $replace = "<b>$word</b>";
            $replace_addr = ucwords(strtolower($addr_result['L_Address'])).", ".$addr_result['L_City'].", ".$addr_result['L_State'].", ".$addr_result['L_Zip'];
            $result_match = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $replace_addr);


            echo '<li id="result"><a href="listing/'.$url_addr.'/'.$addr_result['L_ListingID'].'">'.$result_match.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.. literally nothing is happening when using the arrow keys.

Comment: "literally nothing is happening when using the arrow keys"...well you haven't defined anything to happen for the up arrow. And for the down arrow, `if (resultSelected) {` will never be true because you have not assigned a value to `resultSelected` at the start of the script (or anywhere else except inside that `if` block, which will never be entered). I think you need a clause which finds the first result and selects it, in the case where nothing else is already selected.

Comment: Also the keydown event where you're trying to handle this will only occur when your cursor is focused on the search box - is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, that is intended as far as cursor focus on the box.

Comment: So, the search box is outside of the search results.  When the results are returned, it creates up to 3 different unordered lists.. one for each type of result.  How can i select the nearest UL children when focused on the search box?

Comment: You can do it using JavaScript/jQuery. Without seeing an example of the actual HTML involved, I wouldn't like to be any more specific than that :-)

Comment: css : `ul li:first-child` or add a class and get it `$(this).find('.class');` you want to toogle and show arrows `.toggleClass('arrows up arrows down');` and you need to create css for up down arrows,

Comment: Question edited to include HTML with search box & results.

Comment: Can we assume that the search result lists are all placed within the `searchbox-results` div? If so then finding the first one would simply be `#searchbox-results ul:first li:first-child` - you can find it directly, no need to worry about being relative to the search-term box. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m154x3hj/

Comment: P.S. all those repeated `id="results"` attributes on your `<li>`s are making your HTML invalid. IDs must be unique per element (otherwise what's the point of it being an ID??).

Comment: Thanks for your help ADyson..  figured this out, but i wanted to point out that i completely missed the fact that the div is being repopulated every time there is a keyup trigger... so the class "selected" was being removed every time the result set loaded..  fixed by triggering load results function only if the keys werent arrow keys.